# SQL Tree Query - WITH RECURSIVE & UNION. How to sort by a second value

Tags: sql, sorting, tree

I have a category table with a tree like structure (see image below). For a fast single query, I have the following SQL to get the full tree.

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_tree(id, name, path, position) AS 
(
    SELECT id, name, ARRAY[id], position
    FROM table_name
    WHERE id = id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT table_name.id, table_name.name, path || table_name.id, 
           table_name.position
    FROM search_tree
    JOIN table_name ON table_name.parent_id = search_tree.id
    WHERE NOT table_name.id = ANY(path)
)
SELECT id, name, path, position
FROM search_tree 
ORDER BY path
```

This query result in the following table

```
id  | name         | path    | position
----+--------------+---------+-------------
  1 | Cat Pictures | {1}.    |.    0
  2 | Funny        | {1,2}.  |.    0
  3 | LOLCats      | {1,2,3} |.    1
  4 | Animated     | {1,2,4} |.    2
  5 | Classic      | {1,2,5} |.    0
  6 | Renaissance  | {1,6}   |.    1
```

So the ordering according to path works well. But what I require is to have the order according to the column position, if the path-level is the same level (like id 2 & 4, and 3, 4, 5).

Hence the order of ID would want is

```
ids: 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4
```

[image: Epected data structure]

How to I change my SQL statement to reflect that order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved this way https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rpFiPjKSwHW88C4cp6o9Rm/0

```
with recursive search_tree(id, parentPath, name) as (
    select id, cast(row_number() over(order by pos) as text), name
    from objects
    where parent_id = 0
union all
    select o.id, concat(search_tree.parentPath, ',', cast(row_number() over(order by o.pos) as text)), o.name
    from search_tree
    join objects as o on search_tree.id = o.parent_id
)
select *
from search_tree
order by parentPath;
```

Comment: This does not work. this would result in the order 1, 2, 6, 5, 3, 4. This would brake the whole purpose of this recursive / union all, which give you the tree structure back.

Is there possibly a way to sort by the path, but always exclude the last entry? That's probably the best approach, but I'm no SQL expert.

Comment: So I don't uderstand your requirements well. 2 and 6 is the same path level, so are sorted accorting to column position in the answer. Why is 6 prior 2?

Comment: By getting the order right, it's easy to display the category structure, as they are perfectly lined up with just ONE call to the database (and not one for each category level). Check out this page below for more details (this is also where I got my query from). But I want to go further. I want to be able to control the position in the list, if attributes have the same parent_id. Thx for your help. Happy to upvote your answer again.
https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/recursive-sql-in-activerecord

Comment: OK, I get it. I changed my answer. This will work, but still when you want following id order 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4, you need change position of nodes 2 and 6.